# Sending an array of string to a WSDL Endpoint?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to connect to a webservice. The documentation (or lack of) is here:

http://portal.smartertools.com/services2/

http://portal.smartertools.com/Services2/svcTickets.asmx

I'm attempting to call GetTicketsBySearch. The Args SearchCriteria is a String() and it says "a list of 'key=value' pairs that indicate the search parameters.
To search by custom fields, pass in the id of the field as the key and the search term as the value (ie: 1 = 'value')

My Code:

```
        Dim args As New ST.ArrayOfString
        args.Add("IsOpen='true'")
       Dim CallWebService As New ST.svcTicketsSoapClient
        Dim sGetValue As ST.TicketInfoArrayResult = CallWebService.GetTicketsBySearch(userName, Password, args)
```

I Can't get any results to return. Ive tried passing in the string many different ways. ie: 'IsOpen='true; 'IsOpen'='true' etc...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone else that runs into this specific problem.

- The user account accessing the smartertools endpoint **must** have the role of 'agent' assigned. If it is simply assigned to administrator role or manager role it will not work. This is silly on their part as the agent role requires using a license, so you in effect need to use a license to access their web service.
- If the user account has no permissions, you do not get an error, just no results.
- The correct formatting is no ' example: isOpen=true
- You can not get the description or "body" of the ticket from the GetTickets. Their documentation is incorrect. You can use my code sample below to get the body.

  ```
  '// Loop through your ticket results, or similar
      Dim _ticket As ST.TicketInfo
      _ticket = CType(e.Item.DataItem, ST.TicketInfo)
      Dim CallWebService As New ST.svcTicketsSoapClient
      Dim sGetValue As ST.TicketPartInfoArrayResult = CallWebService.GetTicketConversationPartList(userName, Password, _ticket.ID.tostring())

      '// Just grab the first, if that is all you need
      For Each p In sGetValue.Parts.ToList()
          Dim PVal As ST.TicketMessageBodyResult = CallWebService.GetTicketMessagePlainText(userName, Password, p.PartId)
          Result(PVal.messageBody)
      Next
  ```